# Mapping multi uvs textures to a character in blender? 3 separate textures for character

Tags: uv, export, texture-baking

I've been trying to convert a 3D model into the sims 4 as a decorative object "like action figure." I managed to pose him the way I wish but when it comes to mapping his 3 separate textures I can never seem to correctly do so that he looks the way he does in blender. Can someone give me some detailed help?
[image: model in blender]
[image: exported model with incorrect textures]

Comment: Is it a multiple UV with single material, multiple material with single UV, or something more exotic? uploading your blend file would help.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwlrdf1xr3bez67/rkmodel.blend?dl=0

Comment: can't be sure about it without the textures but it seems that the ks material and rkmodel.png texture and rkuv UVmap are what you need, already done but not applied

Comment: here is the original, it has 3 seperate textures for hair face clothes etc.. i just don't know how to get them all applied to my character https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjb2xajccjjjjca/Kenshin.obj?dl=0

Comment: only original obj mesh, no texture

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/89sokklgs7q2s0p/face1.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2lgwxv4wbxflj9/tex1.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwetrg0ij54jo0w/tex2.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the blend file you sent :
In the UV/image editor, click image and in the menu, new image (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
[image: UV image editor]
[image: new image]
Select the size of your image (512x512 should be enough but let's use 1024x1024), give it a name (like Full Texture) and click ok
[image: image size]
You now have a beautiful black image. This is where we'll bake your texture.
Now go in properties panel, click on vertex data tab and click on rkuv in UV Maps. Make sure the camera icon is active on UVMap.
[image: UV select]
In 3D view, enter Edit mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, salect all with <kbd>A</kbd> and in the UV/Image editor, select the Full Texture", then go back in object mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd> in 3D view)
[image: texture select]
In properties panel, go in render tab, in Bake, bake mode click to open the menu and select "Textures"
[image: bake options]
Click the Bake button. Your Full texture is baking...
[image: bake]
In UV/Image Editor, click Image, Save As image to save your new texture (if you don't, it'll be lost!!)
[image: save image]
In properties panel, go to material tab, select ks material
[image: select mat]
Now go in Texture tab, click the button to change texture and select your brand new Full Texture
[image: select tex]
Back in material tab, delete all but ks materials.
[image: delete mat]
Go in Vertex Data tab and delete "UVMap"
[image: del UV]
Now you have only 1 material with only 1 texture. If it doesn't show, go in material tab, enter edit mode, select all and click the "assign" button. If your texture doesn't show, go in texture tab and click the refresh button.
[image: assign refresh]
now save your file (change the name to keep the original with textures) and you're done !

I don't know much about sims 4 studio, but if you need an OBJ file, open the file menu, select export then wavefront (.obj). give it a name and you'll be able to import it from sims 4 studio and select the Full Texture file as texture. (the old OBJ won't work)
[image: export]

Comment: i think i'm going to have a heart attack....you have no idea how happy you've made me ;_; <--------- tears of joy...

Comment: Glad to help :) I was afraid it was a bit too long to be readable...

Comment: omg no! that was the best method i could have gotten, thank you thank you so much :D

Comment: i hope this can stay here as a reference if i need to look back on it? or should i screenshot everything XD lol

Comment: Don't worry, it'll be here forever!! (well maybe not forever...) but don't forget to accept the answer if it suits your needs. :)

Comment: ahh, yes how do i do that? lol sorry this is literally my first day and post on here

Comment: At the beginning of the answer, on the left, you can click a "checked" icon (accept answer) and up/down arrows (vote up/down)